# How can we create bitbucket repository using curl and credential using ssh key?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to migrate my local git repos to bitbucket but unable to find any API with work without a password. I can't provide the password in credentials as we have logged in using Google account, hence no password. Please help

this is an existing way of creating repos but I can't provide the password.

```
curl --user user:password https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories --data name=$repo --data is_private=true --data owner={repoOwner}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide the BitBucket Cloud account *password*, but you can make an [App password](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html) dedicated just for that usage.

As mentioned [in this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Personal-Access-Token-for-Bitbucket-Cloud/qaq-p/677663):

- [PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html) are not available for BitBucket Cloud
- [App passwords](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html) were introduced ([in 2016](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-11774)) for that kind of usage.

> App passwords have the following benefits:
>
> - **Isolation** – you can have one password per integration / application and manage leaks better.
> - **Scoping** – the app password creation screen allows you to set which permissions the app password should receive so you're not giving away all the keys at once.
> - **Limited functionality** – even with all scopes present, you cannot log into the web UI with an app password. You also cannot create additional app passwords, SSH keys or OAuth tokens with an app password. This makes it harder for someone to use an app password to create a second back door in your account.

Comment: Hi @Vonc, Thanks for responding but unfortunately, mentioned endpoint does not support token-based authentication 

curl --user user:password https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories --data name=$repo --data is_private=true --data owner={repoOwner}

Comment: @shekhardtu App password is not a token. The answer stands.